# Clarifying integral notation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and set $B : = \{ x \in  \mathbb{R}^d : |x| \leq 1\}$. If we denote by $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ the standard scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^d$, then for some $y \in \mathbb{R}^d$ we can consider the integral
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \langle y, x \rangle 1_{B}(x) \, \mu(dx).
$$
Now, how is one supposed to understand the integral in the scalar product
$$
\left\langle y, \int_B x \, \mu (dx)\right\rangle,
$$
and why are the two expressions equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{B}x\mu(dx)=\left(\int_{B}x_{1}\mu(dx),...,\int_{B}x_{n}\mu(dx)\right),
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\left<y,\int_{B}x\mu(dx)\right>=\sum_{k=1}^{n}y_{k}\int_{B}x_{k}\mu(dx)=\int_{B}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}y_{k}\mu(dx)=\int_{B}\left<x,y\right>\mu(dx).
\end{align*}
For general treatment of vector-valued integrals, see Bochner integrals, Pettis integrals, or Bourbaki books on integration. Note that $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ is reflexive, Bochner integrals and Pettis integrals coincide.